# Funnily enough or Funny enough

Tags: grammar, word-usage, grammaticality, adjectives, adverbs

How to say this correctly? In the first sentence I want it to be the way he said it, describing a verb, and in the second one I want to make it the way *he is*, describing a noun.

And what part of speech will they be? And also what part of speech is the word "enough", is it an adverb?

> He said it ***funnily enough*** or He said it ***funny enough***
>
> He is ***funny enough*** or He is ***funnily enough***

Comment: The expression funnily enough is somewhat unique. I don't see why it should be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Funnily enough, I do believe in democracy". [my sentence]

"Funnily enough, he did say he believed in democracy". [my sentence]

**funnily enough** is an idiomatic expression that means that what you say after it is unexpected. It can be placed at the beginning or at the end of a sentence, and not usually in the middle. It is more spoken than written. It is another way of expressing "oddly enough". It is not related to funny, ha ha. It is related to funny as odd or peculiar (see below).

He is funny enough. means: He is sufficiently funny. [ha ha OR odd]
He is rich enough. means: He is sufficiently rich.

Merriam Webster gives it as a adverb from funny, but does not define it.

It would be related in meaning to definitions 3:

> **PECULIAR**  My car has been making a funny noise. —often used as a sentence modifier
>   Funny, things didn't turn out the way we planned.

My car was sputtering funnily. [my sentence]

[funnily](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/funnily)

more funnily enough:

> Funnily enough.
>
> Funnily enough, he loves it.
>
> Funnily enough, it's not.
>
> [Laughs] Funnily enough, yes!
>
> What to? Funnily enough, Redward.
>
> Funnily enough, Bob Fletcher has.
>
> Not McDonald's burgers, funnily enough.
>
> From: guru: Click on the link for the references.

[funnily enough](https://ludwig.guru/s/funnily+enough)

Comment: I have never heard the word *funnily* nor seen it written before now.  MW also lists *funny* as a bare adverb, along with *funnily.*

Comment: I once heard the expression “funnily enough” used in an original episode of *Battlestar Galactica*.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the two meanings of "funnily"

> OED: Funnily 1:  **In an amusing or humorous manner; comically.**
> 1929   Manitoba Free Press 19 Nov. 19/2   *[The play] is produced against settings that are very graceful. Starts funnily and ends more funnily.*
>
> OED: Funnily 2. **Strangely, oddly, curiously; surprisingly. Also frequently as a sentence adverb. Originally and chiefly in *funnily enough.***
>
> 1993   Daily Mail (Nexis) 30 Sept. 3   *Funnily, I can remember none of the things we did in the studio.*
>
> 2001   H. Cross My Summer of Love (2002) 10   *She looked funnily orange from the sunbed.*
>
> 1969   P. Larkin Let. 16 Mar. in Sel. Lett. (1992) 412   ***Funnily enough*** we are conferencing in Belfast next week—they have a new Library.*

Self-produced: A: "I had was talking to Jane and I was telling her that I had not seen John for years when, funnily enough, John came into the room."

> He said it funny enough.

This is non-standard as "funny" is an adjective, and cannot be used to qualify "said", which requires an adverb.

A correct use would be "Is the play funny enough?" in which "funny" = "amusing" and "enough" = sufficiently; to the appropriate degree.